# Как передать результат работы Expect в bash-скрипт

Tags: linux, bash, sh, telnet, expect

Имеется bash-скрипт, который выполняет внутри себя Expect.

Краткий смысл такой, на кроне висит bash-скрипт, который подключается по telnet к маршрутизатору, выполняет некоторую команду и результат этой команды нужно передать в виде переменной обратно в bash для последующего парсинга и обработки.

И я никак не пойму как из expect что-то передать в bash.

Набор команд expect выглядит так:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Команды для expect:
COMM="

#Время ожидание expect
set timeout 1

#Соединение ssh:
spawn telnet 192.168.1.1 23
expect \"*(yes/no)?*\" {send \"yes\r\"}
expect \"Login:\"
send \"$LOGIN\r\"
expect \"Password:\"
send \"$PASSWD\r\"

expect \"*>\"
send \"show interface ${interface_name}\r\"

#Результат этой команды надо вернуть в bash


#Завершение выполнения expect:
expect eof
"
```

Вызов expect делаю так:

```
expect -c "$COMM"
```

Comment: можно пример выполнения команды, а лучше всего диалога? после её выполнения сессия закрывается или выводится приглашение?

Comment: Ну так `expect` куда возвращает всё? В стандартный вывод или ошибку? Вот это и анализируйте.

Comment: @0andriy, претензия мимо... `expect` по умолчанию ничего не пишет в `stdin/err`...

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1439586/how-do-i-get-my-expect-statement-to-not-output-the-stdout-of-the-first-command, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589577/expect-in-bash-script-expect-out-not-printing-out-buffer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210358/expect-output-only-stdout-of-the-command-and-nothing-else, etc. Гуглить что ли разучились?

Comment: Вот пример выполнения подключения и самой команды для получения информации https://yadi.sk/i/FJr6MgQNnf4PLA . Все что выводит команда "show interface PPPoE0" мне и требуется получить

Comment: @RiG, в аду есть отдельный котёл для тех, кто присылает скрины вместо текста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос, вот рабочий пример

```
COMMSHOW="

#Время ожидание expect
set timeout 1

#Соединение ssh:
spawn telnet 192.168.1.1 23
expect \"*(yes/no)?*\" {send \"yes\r\"}
expect \"Login:\"
send \"$LOGIN\r\"
expect \"Password:\"
send \"$PASSWD\r\"

#Выполняемые команды:

expect \"*>\"
send \"show interface ${interface_name}\r\"

expect \"*>\"
puts \"$expect_out(buffer)\"

send \"exit\r\"

#Завершение выполнения expect:
expect eof
"
```

Сам Expect вызываю так, в output лежит ответ

```
output=$(expect -c "$COMMSHOW")
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
NET_INFO="$(expect <<EOF
  log_user 0
  spawn telnet 192.168.1.1 23
  # ...
  expect "Login:"
  send "$LOGIN\r"
  # ...
  send "show interface ${interface_name}\r"
  expect -re "(.*)\r\(.*\)>"
  send_user "\$expect_out(1,string)"
EOF)"
```

Ключевые моменты:

- `log_user 0` — подавить весь лишний вывод `expect`'а
- `expect -re "(.*)\r\(.*\)>"` — ответ сопоставляется регулярному выражению. Первой группе (скобкам) сопоставляется ответ команды, а за ним идёт приглашение
- `expect_out(1,string)` — переменная, в которой хранится то что сопоставила последняя команда `expect`. `1` говорит, что нам нужно то что сопоставлено первой группе регулярного выражения, а `string` — что нам нужен собственно текст. Подробности смотри в [`man expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).
- `send_user "\$expect_out(1,string)"` — отправка в стандартный вывод данной строки. Внимание на то что `\$` перед `expect_out` заэскейпен, дабы bash не пытался его интерпретировать т.к. это переменная самого `expect`.
- `NET_INFO="$(...)"` — обычное присваивание вывода команды переменной.
- `expect <<EOF  ...  EOF` — это *встроенного документ*, *heredoc* bash. К сути вопроса это не относится, но такой синтаксис делает скрипт куда более читаемым.

Comment: У меня ваш пример не работает, видимо из-за log_user 0. Ниже дал ответ, 100% рабочий пример